# Closing one's own question

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Sometimes I ask a question and a helpful commenter points out that the question is ill-founded. This seems like a straight-up case for closing the question, but unfortunately the best I can do is vote to close.

Is there a good reason that users can't close their own questions? If not, can we add that feature?

Comment: Why not just delete the question?

Comment: Because there is a meaningful record of conversation on the question, and deleting it would devalue the contribution made by the commenter who pointed out it was ill-formed. Deleting a question is a harsh prescription when closing would suffice. This goes for one's own questions as well as others'.

Comment: The only thing closing does is prevent new answers to be added. Is that really your goal?

Comment: One could make a CW answer summarising the comment with credit to the commenter and accept it, to flag that you accept the resolution (if not actual answer) of the question.

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais: not quite. Closed questions are basically "not good enough for MathOverflow", and need substantial revision to improve. By closing my own question, I'm either holding it for future revision (for when I figure out exactly what I wanted to ask), or sealing it up and throwing into the archives.

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais Closing will also prevent Community from bumping an unanswered question.